# scons difference between ccflags and shccflags

Tags: scons

What is the reason for having both a CCFLAGS and a SHCCFLAGS variable in the SCons environment?

I am trying to modify a large program build that I did not write myself. When I add the command:

```
env.Append(CCFLAGS=["-I%s" % amber_dir, "-DAMBER"])
```

the compiler runs without the flags I added. But when I do

```
env.Append(SHCCFLAGS=["-I%s" % amber_dir, "-DAMBER"])
```

the compiler adds my flags as wanted. Somewhere in SCons' innards, CCFLAGS are is not passed to SHCCFLAGS. But why have a CCFLAGS and a SHCCFLAGS to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taken from the SCons User's Guide: [SCons Construction Variable](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/a5025.html)

> CCFLAGS
>
> General options that are passed to the C and C++ compilers.
>
> CPPFLAGS
>
> User-specified C preprocessor options. These will be included in any
>   command that uses the C preprocessor, including not just compilation
>   of C and C++ source files via the $CCCOM, $SHCCCOM, $CXXCOM and
>   $SHCXXCOM command lines, but also the $FORTRANPPCOM, $SHFORTRANPPCOM,
>   $F77PPCOM and $SHF77PPCOM command lines used to compile a Fortran
>   source file, and the $ASPPCOM command line used to assemble an
>   assembly language source file, after first running each file through
>   the C preprocessor. Note that this variable does not contain -I (or
>   similar) include search path options that scons generates
>   automatically from $CPPPATH. See $_CPPINCFLAGS, below, for the
>   variable that expands to those options.
>
> SHCCFLAGS
>
> Options that are passed to the C and C++ compilers to generate
>   shared-library objects.
>
> SHCCCOM
>
> The command line used to compile a C source file to a shared-library
>   object file. Any options specified in the $SHCFLAGS, $SHCCFLAGS and
>   $CPPFLAGS construction variables are included on this command line.

The most interesting of the 4 mentioned above are the `SHCCCOM` and `CPPFLAGS` variables. Try your test again setting `CPPFLAGS` instead of `CCFLAGS`.

A general comment about the flags you are setting: with SCons, its generally better to set include paths with the `CPPPATH` variable, and to set defines with the `CPPDEFINES`. When using these variable, you dont need to include the `-I`, nor the `-D` flags, SCons will add it for you in a platform-independent manner. Here's an example:

```
env.Append(CPPPATH=amber_dir)
env.Append(CPPDEFINES='AMBER')
```

You'll need to test this to see if the SharedObject() and/or SharedLibrary() builders use those, I would imagine they would.

Answers to questions in comment below:

`SHCCCOM` is just used to see what the command line looks like, sometimes you may need to use it without using the SCons builders directly. `SHCCFLAGS` is a super-set of `CPPFLAGS` and others and should be used when you have flags that you only want to pass to `SharedLibrary()` or `SharedObject()`. `CPPFLAGS` applies to both static and shared compilations.

Comment: Thanks, everything worked as you suggested. But still confused: when should I used CPPFLAGS, when should I use SHCCFLAGS and when should I use SHCCCOM? Is it just personal preference or is there a reason to use one over the other?